# p:dataTable change order of output

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need help on how to make data table in primefaces, that will output data from database in this form:

### 1st column || 2nd column

### Picture     || Text

### Text        || Picture

### Picture     || Text

### Text        || Picture

### Picture     || Text

### Text        || Picture

### ....

The problem is that i don't know how to change position of this elements on every 2nd row

Comment: did you try something (i guess you are working with a list) ?!?

Comment: create your own java class that can handle three informations (String for text, String for ImageUrl , Boolean) and work with it

Comment: Do it the same as you would do outputting this in plain java to the console. Keep a counter (which there already is) check if it is odd or even and either output the one or the other field. In the second colum reverse the check. Effectively this is not a PrimeFaces issue (plain jsf datatable would be identical)

Comment: @yagamilight: I have a hard time understanding your suggestion in relation to the problem. The op does not state it explicitly, but I assume displaying the same in each column works, but maybe my assumption is wrong

Comment: Post your producer and model of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the solution that i propose to handle this problem

**Step 1** : Create an object that can handle informations

this object will be composed with three informations :

1- info1 : `String`

2- info2 : `String`

3- info3 : `Boolean`

we use `String` because of the informations that we have to handle it has to be `String` you can use it as a `text` and use it as `url` for your picture.

**Step 2** : combining two lists

You can only combine this two lists if they have the same size

```
   Boolean verifie = Boolean.TRUE ; 
   int size = listofText.size(); // they have the same size it means you can use the listofImageUrl
   List<object> listofCombineObject = new Arraylist<>();
   for( int i = 0 , i < size , i++ ){
    if(verifie){
    Object o = new Object();
    o.setinfo1(listofText.get(i));
    o.setinfo2(listofImageUrl.get(i));
    o.setinfo3(verifie);
    verifie = Boolean.FALSE ;        
    }else{
    Object o = new Object();
    o.setinfo1(listofText.get(i));
    o.setinfo2(listofImageUrl.get(i));
    o.setinfo3(verifie);  
    verifie = Boolean.TRUE;         
    }
    }
```

**Step 3** : use rendred in you `dataTable` to show your list

```
    <p:dataTable value="#{ManagedBean.listofCombineObject }" var="object" ...>
    <p:column >
    <h:outputText value="#{object.info1}" rendred="#{object.info3}"/>
    <p:graphicImage id="image" name="#{object.info2}"  rendred="#{!object.info3}"  >
    </p:graphicImage>

    </p:column>
    <p:column >
    <h:outputText value="#{object.info1}" rendred="#{!object.info3}"/>
    <p:graphicImage id="image" name="#{object.info2}"  rendred="#{object.info3}"  >
    </p:graphicImage>
    </p:column> //
```

Hope that helped you